# Displacement settings affecting the mesh luminance

Tags: node-editor

I've added a displacement node following along a tutorial. When I use the same settings as the instructor, my object becomes darker in the render settings viewport using cycles render. When I increase the Scale, then it's more visible. What's causing this to happen?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting a displacement map with the normal input of a shader. That's not a good idea, since they are designed to do two very different things. Remove that connection, or use a regular Vector -> Bump node.